# Why UnsafeRawPointer shows different result when function signatures differs in Swift?

Tags: swift

The code below can be run in a Swift Playground:

```
import UIKit

func aaa(_ key: UnsafeRawPointer!, _ value: Any! = nil) {
    print(key)
}
func bbb(_ key: UnsafeRawPointer!) {
    print(key)
}
class A {
    var key = "aaa"
}
let a = A()
aaa(&a.key)
bbb(&a.key)
```

Here's the result printed on my mac:

```
0x00007fff5dce9248
0x00007fff5dce9220
```

Why the results of two prints differs? What's more interesting, when I change the function signature of **bbb** to make it the same with **aaa**, the result of two prints are the same. And if I use a **global var** instead of **a.key** in these two function calls, the result of two prints are the same. Does anyone knows why this strange behavior happens?

Comment: Inout parameters are passed "copy in/copy out" (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545). The compiler *may* pass the memory location as an optimization, but it is not required to do so. – `withUnsafePointer(to: &a.key) { print($0) }` prints yet another address.

Comment: @MartinR I assume I'm not using an inout parameter. I just use the addess of an object to initialize the UnsafeRawPointer parameter.

Comment: @Hamish That's the most interesting part. In fact, I have seen many uses of this kind (the only difference is they use static var), and these code works perfectly. Because there seems no clear documentation about this usage, maybe I should always use static var in these scenarios?

Comment: @ZhuShengqi: But (as I understand it) the situation is similar. Compare https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17. *"When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeRawPointer argument, it can accept the same operands as UnsafePointer<Type> for any type Type."*  and that is *"An **in-out expression** that contains a mutable variable, property, or subscript reference of type Type"*

Comment: @MartinR Yeah you're right. But I still doubt this is a compiler bug, since using static var or global var always print the same results. Maybe handling inout arguments in some situations is not properly implement in swift compiler?

Comment: As the documentation states, the compiler *may* use pass by reference, but is not bound to do so. You must not rely on it. As @Hamish said, it is an implementation detail, and depends on various factors (such as optimization).

Comment: @MartinR By the way, I think we need the Apple Doc (currently not exist) about the difference between "inout parameter" and "inout expression". There may be a trap here.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks. But since withUnsafePointer(to:_:) always has the correct behavior I want (in fact it should, otherwise this function is of no use), and it also has an inout parameter. So I assume there are implementation difference between these functions with inout parameters. So it is interesting that withUnsafePointer(to:_:) guarantees its implementation detail, while other functions use inout parameters not.

Comment: @Hamish By the way I'm testing which types of variables could be used as keys for associated object, so I'm afraid copy-in copy-out would not help. Now I'm sure either using static or global vars, or always using withUnsafePointer(to:_:) to get the pointer.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks a lot : )

Comment: @ZhuShengqi I have posted an answer hopefully explaining things :) I have also deleted my comments here, as they contained the odd inaccuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the results of two prints differs?

Because for each function call, [Swift is creating a temporary variable](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/c1fc4a1b9fa8135870095ca07ad1f89b#the-use-of-temporary-variables-for-pointer-passing) initialised to the value returned by `a.key`'s getter. Each function is called with a pointer to *their* given temporary variable. Therefore the pointer values will likely not be the same – as they refer to *different* variables.

The reason why temporary variables are used here is because `A` is a non-final class, and can therefore have its getters and setters of `key` *overridden* by subclasses (which could well re-implement it as a computed property).

Therefore in an un-optimised build, the compiler cannot just pass the address of `key` directly to the function, but instead has to rely on calling the getter (although in an optimised build, this behaviour can change completely).

You'll note that if you mark `key` as `final`, you should now get consistent pointer values in both functions:

```
class A {
    final var key = "aaa"
}

var a = A()
aaa(&a.key) // 0x0000000100a0abe0
bbb(&a.key) // 0x0000000100a0abe0
```

Because now the address of `key` *can* just be [directly passed to the functions](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/c1fc4a1b9fa8135870095ca07ad1f89b#direct-pointer-passing-when-the-property-is-final), bypassing its getter entirely.

It's worth noting however that, in general, you **should not** rely on this behaviour. The values of the pointers you get within the functions are a pure implementation detail and are *not* guaranteed to be stable. The compiler is free to call the functions however it wishes, only promising you that the pointers you get will be valid for the duration of the call, and will have pointees initialised to the expected values (and if mutable, any changes you make to the pointees will be seen by the caller).

The *only* exception to this rule is the passing of pointers to global and static stored variables. Swift *does* guarantee that the pointer values you get will be stable and unique for that particular variable. From the Swift team's [blog post on Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6) (emphasis mine):

> However, interaction with C pointers is inherently
>   unsafe compared to your other Swift code, so care must be taken. In
>   particular:
>
> - These conversions cannot safely be used if the callee
>     saves the pointer value for use after it returns. The pointer that
>     results from these conversions is only guaranteed to be valid for the
>     duration of a call. Even if you pass the same variable, array, or
>     string as multiple pointer arguments, you could receive a different
>     pointer each time. **An exception to this is global or static stored
>     variables. You can safely use the address of a global variable as a
>     persistent unique pointer value**, e.g.: as a KVO context parameter.

Therefore if you made `key` a static stored property of `A` or just a global stored variable, you are guaranteed to the get same pointer value in both function calls.

---

#### Changing the function signature

> When I change the function signature of `bbb` to make it the same with `aaa`, the result of two prints are the same

This appears to be an optimisation thing, as I can only reproduce it in -O builds and playgrounds. In an un-optimised build, the addition or removal of an extra parameter has no effect.

<sup>(Although it's worth noting that you should not test Swift behaviour in playgrounds as they are not real Swift environments, and can exhibit different runtime behaviour to code compiled with `swiftc`)</sup>

The cause of this behaviour is merely a coincidence – the second temporary variable is able to reside at the *same* address as the first (after the first is deallocated). When you add an extra parameter to `aaa`, a new variable will be allocated 'between' them to hold the value of the parameter to pass, preventing them from sharing the same address.

The same address isn't observable in un-optimised builds due to the intermediate load of `a` in order to call the getter for the value of `a.key`. As an optimisation, the compiler is able to inline the value of `a.key` to the call-site if it has a property initialiser with a constant expression, removing the need for this intermediate load.

Therefore if you give `a.key` a non-determininstic value, e.g `var key = arc4random()`, then you should once again observe different pointer values, as the value of `a.key` can no longer be inlined.

But regardless of the cause, this is a *perfect* example of how the pointer values for variables (which are not global or static stored variables) are **not** to be relied on – as the value you get can completely change depending on factors such as optimisation level and parameter count.

---

#### `inout` & `UnsafeMutable(Raw)Pointer`

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829907/why-unsaferawpointer-shows-different-result-when-function-signatures-differs-in#comment72776624_42829907):

> But since `withUnsafePointer(to:_:)` always has the correct behavior I want (in fact it should, otherwise this function is of no use), and it also has an `inout` parameter. So I assume there are implementation difference between these functions with `inout` parameters.

The compiler treats an `inout` parameter in a *slightly* different way to an `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter. This is because you can mutate the value of an `inout` argument in the function call, but you cannot mutate the `pointee` of an `UnsafeRawPointer`.

In order to make any mutations to the value of the `inout` argument visible to the caller, the compiler generally has two options:

1. Make a temporary variable initialised to the value returned by the variable's getter. Call the function with a pointer to this variable, and once the function has returned, call the variable's setter with the (possibly mutated) value of the temporary variable.
2. If it's addressable, simply call the function with a *direct* pointer to the variable.

As said above, the compiler cannot use the second option for stored properties that aren't known to be `final` (but this can change with optimisation). However, always relying on the first option can be potentially expensive for large values, as they'll have to be copied. This is *especially* detrimental for value types with copy-on-write behaviour, as they depend on being unique in order to perform direct mutations to their underlying buffer – a temporary copy violates this.

To solve this problem, Swift implements a special accessor – called [`materializeForSet`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/proposals/Accessors.rst#conservative-access-patterns). This accessor allows the callee to either provide the caller with a *direct* pointer to the given variable if it's addressable, or otherwise will return a pointer to a temporary buffer containing a copy of the variable, which will need to be written back to the setter after it has been used.

The former is the behaviour you're seeing with `inout` – [you're getting a *direct* pointer](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/c1fc4a1b9fa8135870095ca07ad1f89b#the-use-of-materializeforset-for-inout) to `a.key` back from `materializeForSet`, therefore the pointer values you get in both function calls are the same.

However, `materializeForSet` is only used for function parameters that require write-back, which explains why it's not used for `UnsafeRawPointer`. If you make the function parameters of `aaa` and `bbb` take `UnsafeMutable(Raw)Pointer`s (which *do* require write-back), you should observe the same pointer values again.

```
func aaa(_ key: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    print(key)
}

func bbb(_ key: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    print(key)
}

class A {
    var key = "aaa"
}

var a = A()

// will use materializeForSet to get a direct pointer to a.key
aaa(&a.key) // 0x0000000100b00580
bbb(&a.key) // 0x0000000100b00580
```

But again, as said above, this behaviour is **not** to be relied upon for variables that are not global or static.

Comment: Did I miss it, or does this not address the scenario OP mentioned when both function signatures are the same? My guess is it's another compiler optimization...

Comment: @mattsven It addresses it by the fact that the pointer values for variables that aren't global or static are an implementation detail and not to be relied upon :) I actually couldn't reproduce the behaviour with an extra argument to the function – I got the same results for each test I did with or without it.

Comment: I got the same behavior as OP in Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: *\*grumbles\** *apple needs to get it together*

Comment: @mattsven I stand corrected – it actually *is* an optimisation thing. I have updated my answer with the details that I could work out (although my warning about playgrounds remains).

Comment: Interesting stuff. Thanks for the dive-in!