# Cannot retrieve associated object

Tags: swift, associated-object

I am setting my associated object in my `cellForRowAt:` method like this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.changeBtn, &self.appointmentHandle, appt, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
cell.changeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeButtonTouch(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

However, in the button touch method I do this:

```
func changeButtonTouch(sender:UIButton) {            
    let assObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, &self.appointmentHandle)
    let appt = assObj as! CHRAppointment
    let changeControl = CHRAppointmentConfirmController()
    changeControl.appointment = appt           
}
```

My associated object there is `nil` every time. Why is it not retrieving the object properly?

Comment: The pointer value to a variable that isn't a static or global is not guaranteed to be stable. Compare [Why UnsafeRawPointer shows different result when function signatures differs in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42829907/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish So how do I fix this then? I need to associate an object with a button so that I can access it in a method when it is touched.

Comment: Use a pointer value to a static or global stored variable – or else provide an `UnsafeRawPointer` with its own unique bit pattern.

Comment: @Hamish Can you please provide an example of this so I can follow your answer better. Thanks.

Comment: Plenty of examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24133058/2976878) :)

Comment: @Hamish I see now. If you'll write that into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I don't think I've said anything that isn't covered by a combination of the two linked Q&As, therefore I'd say closing as a duplicate is the best course of action.

Comment: Why even bother with that? Why not use the `sender`?

Comment: @MihaiFratu The sender doesn't have any of the information I need. It's a UIButton, and I need to access a custom object. I could extend the UIButton into a custom class, but that seems excessive.