# Error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at:

Tags: swift

I am trying to add additional properties to UIViewController.

Code:

```
protocol AdditionalStoredProperties
   {
        associatedtype Title
        func getAssociatedObject<Title>(key: UnsafePointer<Title> , 
defValue : Title)->Title
    }

extension AdditionalStoredProperties
{
    func getAssociatedObject<Title>( key: UnsafePointer<Title> , defValue : Title)->Title
    {
        guard let actual_value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self as! AnyObject, key) as? Title else
        {
            return defValue
        }
        return actual_value
    }

 }

extension UIViewController:AdditionalStoredProperties
{
    typealias Title = String
    var previousPage : String
     {
        get { return getAssociatedObject(&self.previousPage, defValue: self.previousPage) }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &self.previousPage, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)}
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

Error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at:

I know that we cannot directly add stored properties to extensions so I am trying it add using objc_setAssociatedObject()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with what you're doing:

- Attempting to access `self.previousPage` within its own getter will call itself recursively.
- You cannot use `&self.previousPage` as a stable or unique pointer value, as it'll be a pointer to a temporary variable (because you're dealing a computed property). You cannot therefore use it as the key for an associated object. Swift only *guarantees* stable and unique pointer values for static and global stored variables (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42829907/2976878) for more info).
- You should make `AdditionalStoredProperties` a class-bound protocol (with `: class`), as you can only add associated objects to Objective-C classes (which, on Apple platforms, Swift classes are built on top of). While you can bridge, for example, a `struct` to `AnyObject` (it'll get boxed in an opaque Obj-C compatible wrapper), it is merely that; a *bridge*. There's no guarantee you'll get the same instance back, therefore no guarantee the associated objects will persist.
- You probably didn't mean for `Title` to be an associated type of your protocol; you're not using it for anything (the generic placeholder `Title` defined by `getAssociatedObject(key:defValue:)` is completely unrelated).

Bearing those points in mind, here's a fixed version of your code:

```
protocol AdditionalStoredProperties : class {
    func getAssociatedObject<T>(ofType: T.Type, key: UnsafeRawPointer,
                                defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T
}

extension AdditionalStoredProperties {

    func getAssociatedObject<T>(ofType: T.Type, key: UnsafeRawPointer,
                                defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {

        // or: return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, key) as? T ?? defaultValue()
        guard let actualValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, key) as? T else {
            return defaultValue()
        }
        return actualValue
    }
}

extension UIViewController : AdditionalStoredProperties {

    private enum AssociatedObjectKeys {
        static var previousPage: Never?
    }

    var previousPage: String {
        get {
            // return the associated object with a default of "" (feel free to change)
            return getAssociatedObject(ofType: String.self,
                                       key: &AssociatedObjectKeys.previousPage,
                                       defaultValue: "")
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKeys.previousPage,
                                     newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we're:

- Using a `static` stored property in order to get a pointer value to use as the key for our associated object. Again, this works because [Swift guarantees stable and unique pointer values for static and global stored variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42829907/2976878).
- Using `@autoclosure` for the `defaultValue:` parameter, as it may not need to be evaluated if an associated object is already present.
- Having the `key:` parameter take an `UnsafeRawPointer`, as the type of the pointee is irrelevant; it's merely the location in memory that's used as the key.
- Explicitly satisfying the generic placeholder with an `ofType:` parameter. This is mainly a matter of preference, but I prefer to spell these things out explicitly rather than relying on type inference.
- Using `camelCase` instead of `snake_case`, as is Swift convention.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback and pointing out exactly where I went wrong. I should have noticed the mistake with recursive call to self.

Comment: This is a great answer. Especially point 2 (referencing a temporary variable) was very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

If someone has the below scenario

> **If your method is getting called recursively, you may get this error.**